# How to access the "id_token" and "refresh_token" when using spring-security-oauth2 client with OpenID Connect provider?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, openid-connect

I have successfully integrated Spring Security OAuth2 with my Open ID Connect provider (Forgerock OpenAM). I can see the access token being retrieved. How can I access the `id_token` and `refresh_token` which are part of the response from the `/token` endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I hope this helps anyone looking for the response.

Use your “Authentication authentication” object:

```
OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauth2Auth = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;
String idToken = ((DefaultOidcUser) oauth2Auth.getPrincipal()).getIdToken().getTokenValue();
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out answer and posting in case it is useful for someone with the same problem. After session is authenticated by Spring Security OAuth2, there is an `Authentication` Object setup. It needs to get casted to an instance of `OAuth2Authentication`. That object has the token.

```
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth instanceof OAuth2Authentication) {
        Object details = auth.getDetails();
        OAuth2AccessToken token = oauth2Ctx.getAccessToken();

        if (token != null && !token.isExpired()) {
            // Do Stuff
        }
```

Comment: What about idToken? Can we get it?

Answer (score 0):

A complete example of an alternative approach (using Spring Boot and disabling part of its autoconfiguration).

application.properties:

```
security.oauth2.client.client-id=client-id
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=client-secret
security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri=http://my-oidc-provider/auth/oauth2/token
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri=http://my-oidc-provider/auth/oauth2/authorize
security.oauth2.resource.token-info-uri=http://my-oidc-provider/auth/oauth2/check_token
security.oauth2.client.scope=openid,email,profile
security.oauth2.resource.jwk.key-set-uri=http://my-oidc-provider/auth/oidc/jwks
```

```java
/**
 * Extending the AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration disables the Spring
 * Boot ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration {

    @Value("${security.oauth2.resource.jwk.key-set-uri}")
    private String keySetUri;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.resource.token-info-uri}")
    private String checkTokenEndpointUrl;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.client-id}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.client-secret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Bean
    public RemoteTokenServices resourceServerTokenServices() {
        RemoteTokenServices tokenService = new RemoteTokenServices();

        DefaultAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter = new DefaultAccessTokenConverter();
        accessTokenConverter.setUserTokenConverter(new CustomIdTokenConverter(keySetUri));
        tokenService.setAccessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter);

        tokenService.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl(checkTokenEndpointUrl);
        tokenService.setClientId(clientId);
        tokenService.setClientSecret(clientSecret);

        return tokenService;
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService() {
        return new InMemoryClientDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserInfoRestTemplateFactory userInfoRestTemplateFactory(
            ObjectProvider<List<UserInfoRestTemplateCustomizer>> customizers,
            ObjectProvider<OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails> details,
            ObjectProvider<OAuth2ClientContext> oauth2ClientContext) {
        return new DefaultUserInfoRestTemplateFactory(customizers, details,
                oauth2ClientContext);
    }
}
```

```java
public class CustomIdTokenConverter extends DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter {

    private final JwkTokenStore jwkTokenStore;

    public CustomIdTokenConverter(String keySetUri) {
        this.jwkTokenStore = new JwkTokenStore(keySetUri);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication extractAuthentication(Map<String, ?> map) {

        String idToken = (String) map.get("id_token");

        OAuth2AccessToken token = jwkTokenStore.readAccessToken(idToken);

        Map<String, Object> claims = token.getAdditionalInformation();
        OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken = token.getRefreshToken();

        String principal = (String) claims.get("sub");

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER");

        return new CustomAuthenticationData(principal, claims, authorities);
    }
}
```

```java
public class CustomAuthenticationData extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken {

    private final Map<String, Object> attributes;

    public CustomAuthenticationData(String username, Map<String, Object> attributes, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, "N/A", authorities);
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like this is very specific to using JWT tokens which are signed by JWKs. Does this also work with opaque tokens?

Comment: Access token and refresh token could be opaque tokens, but OpenID Connect defines the `id_token` as a JWT and that is the reason for parsing it using the `JwkTokenStore` class.